# Inject within Guice to ManagedBean JSF

Tags: jsf, guice

i have a problem injecting within a Guice (`@Inject`) a repository class to a `@ManagedBean`  class (JSF), which is using `EntityManager` to get info from db. I've read a lot of old articles with strange ways to do it, but nothing worked. Here is the code:

```
public class InitConfigListener extends GuiceServletContextListener {

    @Override
    protected Injector getInjector() {
        return Guice.createInjector(new ServletModule() {

            @Override
            protected void configureServlets() {
                install(new JpaPersistModule("db-manager"));

                filter("/*").through(PersistFilter.class);
            }
        }, new RepositoryModule());
    }

}
public class RepositoryModule extends AbstractModule {

    public void configure() {
        bind(IBookRepository.class).to(BookRepository.class).asEagerSingleton();
        bind(IUserRepository.class).to(UserRepository.class).asEagerSingleton();
    }

}

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class BooksView {

    private List<Book> bookList;
    private IBookRepository booksRepository;

    public BooksView() { }

    @Inject
    public BooksView(IBookRepository booksRepository) {
        this.booksRepository = booksRepository;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void initBookList() {
        bookList = booksRepository.getAll();
    }

    public List<Book> getBookList() {
        return bookList;
    }

    public void setBookList(List<Book> bookList) {
        this.bookList = bookList;
    }

}
```

EntityManager was injected in repositories. After bindings of repositories, `@Inject` in class `BooksView` didn't executed, `@PostConstruct` was and repository injected was null.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Why is there `@Inject` over the parameterized constructor?

Comment: @Tiny: This is Guice, not CDI (Guice and Spring DI were "legacy predecessors" to CDI). Other rules may apply, I'm not sure either.

Answer (score 0):

Guice works a little bit differently to CDI as BalusC mentioned.

What is happening is that the CDI is executing properly and calling the post constructs on the methods.
JSF Classes are also not Guice managed but CDI Managed so you need to call guice from your front end (which is correct) unless you are using servlet based web fronts, where you use **guice-servlet** can get around this. Method annotations also require **aopalliance**.

You can initialize Guice through a filter (example : https://github.com/GedMarc/JWebSwing-Undertow/blob/master/src/main/java/za/co/mmagon/jwebswing/undertow/UndertowJWebSwingHandlerExtension.java) for undertow based containers, or as a ServletContextListener as mentioned here (https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ServletModule) if you would like to startup before a @PostConstruct in a JSF view.

An interesting thing as well, is in an EE environment, the @PostConstruct timing is different in @Singleton's. In standalone environments you can place the injection builder in this location to load injections for ejb and servlets (from a module in the war)

Comment: _"JSF Classes are also not Guice managed but CDI Managed "_ This is wrong. JSF 'classes' (managedbeans) are JSF managed, not CDI

Answer (score 0):

You can use Guice as long as you configure JSF Appropriately.

In a nutshell, to do this you need to enable two things
 - Set a custom application factory
 - Configure EL to get the bindings from Guice

Set the application factory via the faces-config.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config version="2.1" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd">
    <factory>
        <application-factory>com.jwebmp.guicedservlets.jsf.FacesApplicationFactoryWrapper</application-factory>
    </factory>

</faces-config>
```

A servlet context parameter (web.xml) or for undertow/embeddeds a deployment info

```
com.sun.faces.facesInitializerMappingsAdded=true

deploymentInfo.addServletContextAttribute(RIConstants.FACES_INITIALIZER_MAPPINGS_ADDED, Boolean.TRUE)
                 .addListener(new ListenerInfo(com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.class));
```

Then in your module - 
Use your choice mechanism of scanning, and bind all @javax.inject.Named and @ManagedBean to keys you are going to use in the Guice EL Resolver replacing the CDI/CustomInject/any form on injection that JSF uses with Guice.

[Module Binder Example Here](https://github.com/GedMarc/Guiced-Servlets-JSF/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jwebmp/guicedservlets/jsf/implementations/JsfNamedBinder.java)

[Guice EL Resolver Example Here](https://github.com/GedMarc/Guiced-Servlets-JSF/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jwebmp/guicedservlets/jsf/GuiceELResolverWrapper.java)

[Faces Application Wrapper](https://github.com/GedMarc/Guiced-Servlets-JSF/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jwebmp/guicedservlets/jsf/FacesApplicationWrapper.java)

[Optional View Scope Impl](https://github.com/GedMarc/Guiced-Servlets-JSF/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jwebmp/guicedservlets/jsf/ViewScopeImpl.java)

---

Below is a bundled implementation which you can simply attach, using the Guiced EE framework for JDK 11 and up in modular JPMS (backwards compatible to 1.8)

Note * because of the invalid ServiceProviders in the javax.faces library, the framework references a local javax.faces which at time of updating this was at 2.3.9 with the providers removed to enable you building your JRE with JLink or simply executing your application in JPMS

https://github.com/GedMarc/Guiced-Servlets-JSF

```
https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.jwebmp.guicedee.servlets/guiced-servlets-jsf/0.68.0.1/jar
```

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.jwebmp.guicedee.servlets</groupId>
  <artifactId>guiced-servlets-jsf</artifactId>
  <version>0.68.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Then you can just use @ManagedBean and/or @Named (JSF2.3) appropriately with all injections in pretty much any environment, except Servlet 4 which guice-servlet does not yet support

Comment: JSF 2.4 doesn't exist and @Named is not part of JSF but CDI. Your answer is therefore a bit confusing. Can you please review your answer?

Comment: JSF 2.4 is available at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.4.0
JSF 2.4 replaces all @ ManagedBean with @ Named and marks @ ManagedBean usage as deprecated
JSF 2.4 removes the custom DI with CDI and is correct as well.

I'm not sure I understand your comment - I do believe this answer is 100% valid?

Comment: http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2018/04/do-not-use-orgglassfish-mojarra-240.html Summary: it's a Mojarra 2.3.3-clone which has been mistakenly published to Maven as Mojarra 2.4.0 implementation. Do not ever use it. JSF 2.4 API does even not exist at all. The highest available is JSF 2.3 API. All what you describe is only true for JSF 2.3 API. So please replace "2.4" by "2.3" and all is well. Do not advocate users to use Mojarra 2.4.0.